# Http POST request succeeds in Java but fails in C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, webrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to send a simple HTTP POST request to a web service and read the response. I need to do this in a .NET project but the call fails all the time. I tested to call the same web service in Java and it went with no problems at all.

Here's my code in C#:

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "web service URI");


        string json = "some json input";
        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");            
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();       
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*");                                                                                                                    
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

        try
        {               
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> httpRequest = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead
                , CancellationToken.None);

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpRequest.Result;
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
            HttpContent responseContent = httpResponse.Content;
            if (responseContent != null)
            {
                Task<string> stringContentTask = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string stringContent = stringContentTask.Result;
                return stringContent;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Response content is null.");
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            List<Exception> innerExceptions = ae.InnerExceptions.ToList();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Exception e in innerExceptions)
            {
                sb.Append(e.Message).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    sb.Append(e.InnerException.Message).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

The code fails when I call httpRequest.Result. The ultimate exception message is the following:

"Unable to read data from the transport connection: the connection was closed."

However, when I try the same in Java it works perfectly. Here's my Java code:

```
String url = "web service URI";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close");
        String content = "some json";
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(content);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + content);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

For the C# part I tested other http-related objects in .NET: HttpWebRequest and WebClient, only to get the same exception message.

I'm suspecting that the .NET objects add some type of header or a default setting which must be disabled, but I don't know what it is.

FYI:
- the Java code works even if I remove all the calls to setRequestProperty, so the code passes without explicitly setting "User-Agent", "Accept-Language" etc.
- the web service is set up to close the connection immediately after the communication is over, i.e. there's no keep-alive available. I seem to recall that this feature is "disliked" by .NET web client objects, but I wouldn't bet my life on it.
- you'll notice that I set ExpectContinue to false in C# but not in Java. In Java it's apparently no necessary whereas I had to switch this off in other C# projects to make the call work. I tested to set it to true without any difference in the result.

Any suggestions are welcome. I have no control over the web service settings so please don't suggest anything that requires such a change.

Thanks,
Andras

Comment: Did you checked with my answer

Comment: Try the same code without cache-control header

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not adding the connection header.  First of all, with the HttpClient if you wanted to ask the server to close the connection after the request you would do

```
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

Http 1.1 uses keep-alive by default, so there is no need to send the header.  If the server returns `Connection: close` then the client should handle that just fine.

HttpClient does get a bit upset when you start messing with headers that it wants to have control over.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I removed all header declarations and added the connectionclose = true bit but I'm still getting the same exception unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try Fiddler Web Debugging Proxy. It may help to find the difference in HTTP traffic ([fiddler2.com](http://fiddler2.com)).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Your URL");
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Post Input");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json"; //you can set application/xml
        request.ContentType = "application/json";// you can set application/xml
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader result = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        if( result !=null)
        {
        if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(result.ReadToEnd().ToString()))
        {
          MessageBox.Show(result.ReadToEnd().ToString());
        }
        }
```